# Does concentration of zero-order reactant affect half-life?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

> Two substances $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ react with each other in such a way that $\ce{A}$ is $50\,\%$ consumed in $\pu{33 min}$ and $75\,\%$ consumed in $\pu{66 min}.$ Changing the concentration of $\ce{B}$ has no effect on the results. Which statement is true?

And the answer is:

> This reaction is first order in $\ce{A}$ and zero-order in $\ce{B}.$

I understand why $\ce{A}$ is first order but I don't get why $\ce{B}$ is zero order. The equation for the half-life of a zero order reactant is $$t_{1/2} = \frac{[\ce{B}]_0}{2k}.$$

Doesn't this mean that the concentration for a zero-order reactant would affect the half-life?

Comment: How can we conclude that $A$  is first order?

Comment: Some information is missing. You ask : Which statement is true ? OK. But there are no statements to consider for a choice !...

Answer (score 3):

> Changing the concentration of $\ce{B}$ has no effect on the results.

This statement could only mean one thing: $\ce{B}$ does not participate in the reaction. Obviously, if $\ce{B}$ does participate in the reaction, and you change the concentration of $\ce{B}$ to $0,$ the reaction won't happen.

> The equation for the half-life of a zero order reactant is $$t_{1/2} = \frac{[\ce{B}]_0}{2k}.$$

Zero order reaction have no half-life. Only 1st order reaction has half-life.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly! The concentration of B during the reaction does not effect the half life. If you see for the zero order reactions, the half life can be written as $\frac{B_{\text{initial}}}{2K}$ in which B & K are constants. So for zero order reactions, half life  does not depend upon the concentration of reactants at any time (after start of the reaction).

Comment: But you are changing the initial concentration of B. I thought first order half lives were not affected by the initial concentration.

Answer (score 0):

Let the rate law for the reaction be $$r = k[\ce{A}]^n[\ce{B}]^m$$

> Changing the concentration of B has no effect on the results.

What are the results? Is it the rate? or is it the half life?

***Finding the value of  $\mathbf{m}$***

**1. If it is the rate, then**

It is obvious that $m$ should be zero.

**2. If it is the half life, then**

For this to happen, $m$ should be equal to $1$$^*$, because only for a first order or a *pseudo* first order reaction, half life is independent of initial concentration of reactant.

---

*This is correct only if A is in excess